# In honor of Franz Schubert’s birthday, January 31

Tags: alphametic

Franz Peter Schubert was born on January 31, 1797.

Here is a skeletal division. Each music note denotes an odd or even digit.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Franz_Schubert

[image: alphametic puzzle about Schubert]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The answer:**

> [image: 10697853/31]

**Notes:**

> 31×1=31  ♪♪
> 31×2=62  ♫♫
> 31×3=93  ♪♪
> 31×4=124 ♪♫♫
> 31×5=155 ♪♪♪
> 31×6=186 ♪♫♫
> 31×7=217 ♫♪♪
> 31×8=248 ♫♫♫
> 31×9=279 ♫♪♪

Yes, this is enough to solve the problem. Place correct digits in the correct places considering odd/even-ness. And we need a few logical deductions, but they are *too* simple.